# How to get list of available display modes in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to create a custom page with combo box, that will contain all available display resolutions and color modes. I've found [this example for Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/a/change_display.htm), but the `TDevmode` class is not supported in InnoSetup as far as I know.

Can anyone show, how to fill a combo box only with 16-bit and 32-bit color display modes ?

Example:

```
1024 x 768 16 Bit
1024 x 768 32 Bit
```

Comment: TDeviceMode is not a class, it's a record ([_devicemodeW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552837(v=vs.85).aspx))and you can declare it in your script.

Comment: Alright, I have the record but I can't get the whole thing working. I don't know how to declare and call the EnumDisplaySettings function.

Comment: Note that each user may have their own custom desktop resolution, so asking for something related to that in a per-machine installer is not especially useful.  Perhaps this is something you should defer until first-run of your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  CCHFORMNAME = 32;
  CCHDEVICENAME = 32;  
type
  TDeviceMode = record
    dmDeviceName: array[0..CCHDEVICENAME - 1] of Char;
    dmSpecVersion: Word;
    dmDriverVersion: Word;
    dmSize: Word;
    dmDriverExtra: Word;
    dmFields: DWORD;
    dmOrientation: Smallint;
    dmPaperSize: Smallint;
    dmPaperLength: Smallint;
    dmPaperWidth: Smallint;
    dmScale: Smallint;
    dmCopies: Smallint;
    dmDefaultSource: Smallint;
    dmPrintQuality: Smallint;
    dmColor: Smallint;
    dmDuplex: Smallint;
    dmYResolution: Smallint;
    dmTTOption: Smallint;
    dmCollate: Smallint;
    dmFormName: array[0..CCHFORMNAME - 1] of Char;
    dmLogPixels: Word;
    dmBitsPerPel: DWORD;
    dmPelsWidth: DWORD;
    dmPelsHeight: DWORD;
    dmDisplayFlags: DWORD;
    dmDisplayFrequency: DWORD;
    dmICMMethod: DWORD;
    dmICMIntent: DWORD;
    dmMediaType: DWORD;
    dmDitherType: DWORD;
    dmICCManufacturer: DWORD;
    dmICCModel: DWORD;
    dmPanningWidth: DWORD;
    dmPanningHeight: DWORD;
  end;
  TDeviceFilter = record
    Width: DWORD;
    Height: DWORD;
    BitDepth: DWORD;
  end;

function EnumDisplaySettings(lpszDeviceName: string; iModeNum: DWORD;
  var lpDevMode: TDeviceMode): BOOL;
  external 'EnumDisplaySettings{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  ModeIndex: DWORD;
  ModeExists: Boolean;
  FilterIndex: Integer;  
  DisplayPage: TWizardPage;
  DisplayCombo: TNewComboBox;
  DisplayModes: array of TDeviceFilter;
  DisplaySettings: TDeviceMode;
begin
  DisplayPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  DisplayCombo := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  DisplayCombo.Parent := DisplayPage.Surface;
  DisplayCombo.Style := csDropDownList;
  DisplayCombo.Width := 200;

  ModeIndex := 0;
  while EnumDisplaySettings('', ModeIndex, DisplaySettings) do
  begin    
    with DisplaySettings do
    begin
      Inc(ModeIndex);
      if (dmBitsperPel <> 16) and (dmBitsperPel <> 32) then
        Continue;

      ModeExists := False;
      for FilterIndex := 0 to GetArrayLength(DisplayModes) - 1 do
      begin
        if (DisplayModes[FilterIndex].Width = dmPelsWidth) and
          (DisplayModes[FilterIndex].Height = dmPelsHeight) and
          (DisplayModes[FilterIndex].BitDepth = dmBitsperPel) then
        begin
          ModeExists := True;
          Break;
        end;
      end;

      if not ModeExists then
      begin        
        SetArrayLength(DisplayModes, GetArrayLength(DisplayModes) + 1);
        with DisplayModes[GetArrayLength(DisplayModes) - 1] do
        begin
          Width := dmPelsWidth;
          Height := dmPelsHeight;
          BitDepth := dmBitsperPel;
          DisplayCombo.Items.Add(Format('%dx%d %d bpp', [Width, 
            Height, BitDepth]));
        end;      
      end;
    end;    
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that you've specified in your question that you need to get modes for 16 and 32 bit depth, but you didn't considered, that devices may have many of them differing in some attributes, like display frequency and that's not taken into account in this script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works as intended! Just one question: all resolutions are shown at least two or three times. I guess this might be because of frame rates or other settings which are not shown and thus are not necessary. How can I get rid of those multiple entries?

Comment: That's what I've mentioned in my comment. On my laptop they differ in more than just display frequency. I'll make an update to this... So do you want to have just one resolution and bit depth as one item, right ? Without considering frequency etc. ?

Comment: Ah, didn't see you mentioned it... Correct, as I explained in my question. The frequency and so on do not have to be taken into consideration, only the resolution and 16/32 bit color modes.

Comment: Great! One more thing that came to my mind: can you also add a filter for certain resolutions that should be excluded? Because resolutions under 640 x 480 are useless...

Comment: @user IMHO adding that filter is easy enough for you to try!! You have ebough help with this and you may want to excercise a bit!! ;)